# Blender Python giving wrong coordinates for vertex in mesh

Tags: python, scripting, 3d, iteration, blender

I'm attempting to make a Blender Python script to import a proprietary but documented height map format from a game ([format documentation](https://zeldamods.org/wiki/HGHT)).

The game stores it's height data in chunks, and each chunk is 256x256 vertices. The problem I initially encountered was that the chunks had obvious seams where the chunk's edges meet. I later discovered that you actually need a 257x257 grid of vertices, and the top and right edge of the mesh need to be stitched to the corresponding edges of the top and right bordering chunks.

I made a part in my script that iterates over each vertex and checks if it's bordering the top or right chunk, then changes it's Z position to match the bordering chunk's vertex to make it appear as one while keeping the chunks separate. It's not the most efficient way to do it, as I could just make it iterate over the edge vertices instead of all of them, but it works for now (mostly).

My main issue is when it reaches the top right corner vertex of my chunk, which happens to be the last vertex in the `bm.verts` list. When my script tries to get the Z position of the corresponding vertex from the top or right chunk, it mistakenly gets `0.0`. This just makes an obvious hole in all of the chunks with bordering top and right chunks, and I can't figure out if this is a bug or my code is just wrong. I even tried manually changing the vertex in code and printing the Z position of the vertex I got the value from, and its always just `0.0`.

Here is the script at the moment, it's a little messy but that's because I've tried a bunch of things to try and solve the problem:

```py
for obj in objects:
    
    # Get Z-order location and bordering chunks
    z = int(obj.name[2:], base=16)
    top    = (((z & 0b10101010) - 1) & 0b10101010) | (z & 0b01010101)
    right  = (((z | 0b10101010) + 1) & 0b01010101) | (z & 0b10101010)
    top_tile_name = obj.name[:2] + hex(top).replace('x', '').zfill(8).upper()
    right_tile_name = obj.name[:2] + hex(right).replace('x', '').zfill(8).upper()
    
    mesh = bmesh.new()
    mesh.from_mesh(obj.data)
    mesh.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    
    print('Top tile: ' + top_tile_name)
    print('Right tile: ' + right_tile_name)
    
    # Check if top bordering chunk exists
    if top_tile_name in [object.name for object in objects]:
        top_tile = bmesh.new()
        top_tile.from_mesh(bpy.data.objects[top_tile_name].data)
        top_tile.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
        
        # Stitch top edge vertices to bordering chunk vertex
        for vert in range(257 * 257):
            x = vert % 257
            y = vert // 257
            if y == 256:
                mesh.verts[vert].co.z = top_tile.verts[x].co.z
        mesh.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    
    # Check if right bordering chunk exists
    if right_tile_name in [object.name for object in objects]:
        right_tile = bmesh.new()
        right_tile.from_mesh(bpy.data.objects[right_tile_name].data)
        right_tile.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
        
        # Stitch right edge vertices to bordering chunk vertex
        for vert in range(257 * 257):
            x = vert % 257
            y = vert // 257
            if x == 256:
                mesh.verts[vert].co.z = right_tile.verts[vert - 256].co.z
        mesh.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    
    mesh.to_mesh(obj.data)
    obj.data.update()
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think I *half* fixed the problem, I just changed:

```py
for obj in objects:
```

to this:

```py
for obj in reversed(objects):
```

And while it does iterate backwards, it somehow fixes the issue by doing so.